# when click delete button of actioncolumn/yii2,i want to refresh the rows of gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax, yii2-advanced-app

i know how to refresh part of a page using pjax of yii2.

but how to change the default action(it may jump to new url opening a new page) of actioncolumn buttons to do the same thing: refresh only the gridview part?

Comment: Your question is vague. what exactly you want to do? Do you want to open a new page on actioncolumn button click?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$.pjax.reload({container: '#gridId'});
```